# Error in t(as(from, “ngCMatrix)): error in evaluating the argument ‘x’ in selecting a method for function ‘t’: Error in asM

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, knime

I'm using R code in Knime, a platform for data analytics. I take a matrix from a block which reads a table from an xls file. This matrix is called "my_matrix". Then I'd like to applicate the apriori algorithm to three columns of this matrix, but I get the above error. Any ideas?
Please note that "sum(is.na(my_matrix))" has output [1] 0

```
require(arules)
#require(arulesViz)

#some code to retreive the my_matrix

#my_matrix
my_rows= nrow(my_matrix);
my_cols= ncol(my_matrix);
matrix_temp = my_matrix[,4:5];
matrix_temp = array(c(matrix_temp, my_matrix[,20]), dim=c(my_rows,3))
#matrix_temp
my_matrix = matrix_temp

sum(is.na(my_matrix)) #output: [1] 0

my_transactions = as(my_matrix, "transactions");
summary(my_transactions)
```

my_matrix is a table in which columns are this type: (String, Integer, Integer, String, String, Integer, Double, Integer, Double, Double, Integer, Double, Double, Integer, Double, Double, Integer, Double, Integer, String). There are 3300 rows in the table.

```
> my_matrix = as(knime.in, "matrix")
> dput(head(my_matrix, 5))
structure(c("KS", "OH", "NJ", "OH", "OK", "128", "107", "137", 
" 84", " 75", "415", "415", "415", "408", "415", "noIP", "noIP", 
"noIP", "IP", "IP", "Vmail", "Vmail", "noVmail", "noVmail", "noVmail", 
"25", "26", " 0", " 0", " 0", "265.1", "161.6", "243.4", "299.4", 
"166.7", "110", "123", "114", " 71", "113", "45.07", "27.47", 
"41.38", "50.90", "28.34", "197.4", "195.5", "121.2", " 61.9", 
"148.3", " 99", "103", "110", " 88", "122", "16.78", "16.62", 
"10.30", " 5.26", "12.61", "244.7", "254.4", "162.6", "196.9", 
"186.9", " 91", "103", "104", " 89", "121", "11.01", "11.45", 
" 7.32", " 8.86", " 8.41", "10.0", "13.7", "12.2", " 6.6", "10.1", 
" 3", " 3", " 5", " 7", " 3", "2.70", "3.70", "3.29", "1.78", 
"2.73", "1", "1", "0", "2", "3", "notChurning", "notChurning", 
"notChurning", "notChurning", "notChurning"), .Dim = c(5L, 20L
), .Dimnames = list(c("Row0", "Row1", "Row2", "Row3", "Row4"), 
    c("State", "Account length", "Area code", "International plan", 
    "Voice mail plan", "Number vmail messages", "Total day minutes", 
    "Total day calls", "Total day charge", "Total eve minutes", 
    "Total eve calls", "Total eve charge", "Total night minutes", 
    "Total night calls", "Total night charge", "Total intl minutes", 
    "Total intl calls", "Total intl charge", "Customer service calls", 
    "Churn")))
```

I have modified my code as below. I have no errors now, but the apriori algorithm founds no rules:

```
    require(arules)
    #require(arulesViz)
    my_matrix= as(knime.in,"matrix");
    my_rows= nrow(my_matrix);
    my_cols= ncol(my_matrix);
    my_matrix = append(my_matrix[,4:5], my_matrix[,20])
    my_matrix <- array(my_matrix, dim=c(my_rows, 3))
    head(my_matrix, 2)
    my_cols = 3
    my_dedup_matrix= matrix(nrow=my_rows, ncol=my_cols);
    for (i in 1:my_rows) {
        m = my_matrix[i,];
        my_unique= unique(m);
        for (j in 1:my_cols) {
            my_dedup_matrix[i,j] = my_unique[j];
        }
    }
    my_new_data= apply(my_dedup_matrix, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]);
    my_transactions = as(as.list(my_new_data), "transactions");
    summary(my_transactions)



## Mine association rules.
rules = apriori(my_transactions, parameter = list(supp= 0.1, conf= 0.8, target = "rules"));
summary(rules); # no rules found
inspect(rules); # no rules found
#inspect(rules[1:10])
```

Comment: Something is wrong here.  You state that some colums are Double. Can you go to the Knime Node prior to the R node and make a screenshot of the Second tab (the one which shows the domains)

Comment: Your confidence is quite high. Set it to zero and slowly increase until you find a reasonable set of rules.

Comment: I have put confidence = 0.1, but I obtain rules like: {}  => {noVmail}

Comment: This basically means that in 10% of the cases there is noVmail. It is a very valid rule. 
I think this is not a technical problem anymore but merely a question of how to use apriori. Adjusting support and confidence is indeed a bit tricky. Helping here would require to have you full dataset.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you very much. Who knows how the similar question I have submitted with the other account will end up?

Comment: I should also practice my english, in addition to R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert my_matrix first into a list.
`as(as.list(my_matrix),"transactions")`
However, I get a different error.

```
as(as.list(matrix_temp),"transactions")
transactions in sparse format with
 15 transactions (rows) and
 5 items (columns)
```

Comment: With you original code ` my_transactions = as(my_matrix, "transactions");` I got `Error in asMethod(object) : 
  matrix is not logical or a numeric 0-1 matrix!`

Comment: I have no error now. I have modified my code following your trick as you can see in my edited question. However, the apriori alghoritm gives me no rules

Comment: I think it would have been better to except the answer and make a new question. My answer is now dangling around. Added a comment above.

Comment: there's someting weird: I have tried to get rules using knime boxes, but I got much more rules